# macOS Sierra上でXcode7.3.1を利用すると新規プロジェクトの画面が崩れる

Tags: swift, xcode

Xcode7.3.1にてプロジェクトを作成したいのですが、文字がずれて重なってしまい、下の画像のようになってしまいます。
Xcodeの再インストールも行いましたが、改善しませんでした。
改善の方法をご存知な方はおられないでしょうか？

[image: xcode 7.3.1 で画面が崩れる]

Answer (score 2):

macOS Sierra 10.12.1とXcode 7.3.1の組み合わせで、添付画像と同じ不具合を確認しました。
macOS Sierra 10.12.1とXcode 8.1では、問題は起きません。
macOS El Capitan 10.11.xとXcode 7.3.1でも、問題が起きた経験はありません。
なお、数分間Xcodeを操作した範囲では、新規プロジェクト作成画面だけで文字がずれて表示されるだけで、ほかに不具合がありそうには見えませんでした。

以上から、Xcode 7.3.1のバージョンが前提なら、macOSのバージョンをEl Capitanに戻すか、別のEl Capitanで動いているMacに、Xcode 7.3.1をインストールして使用するかということになると思います。